# Create a strip above footer - css/html

Tags: html, css

I require some assistance with CSS. I am trying to create a stripe above the footer where for desktop I have image on the left, the text next to it and then the form input fields and button on the right. I have attached the current desktop look where the issue is that I want the text next to the image to be vertically in the centre and the form fields to be more on the right.

Current Desktop:

[image]

For mobile: I want the text to be displayed next to the image (can break into two lines) and them the form fields to move up so it's underneath the image and text.

Current Mobile:

[image]

Can somebody help with the above?

HTML:

```
<div id="text-5">

    <div class="left_footer_strip"><img src="https://shop.balancecoffee.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/ezgif.com-gif-maker-1.gif" alt="Join Balance"/></div>
    
    <p class="middle_footer_strip">Join Balance and get 20% off your first order</p>
    
    //form fields
    <div class="klaviyo-form-Re6W9v right_footer_strip"></div>

</div>
```

CSS:

/*FOOTER*/

```
#text-5{
    width:100% !important;
}

.footer_wrap_inner > .content_wrap{
    width:100% !important;
}

.left_footer_strip,
.middle_footer_strip{
    float:left;
}

.left_footer_strip{
    padding-right:20px;
}

.middle_footer_strip{
    font-size:24px !important;
}
```

Comment: The code you provided does not produce an output similar to that in the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS Flexbox:

```css
#text-5 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 2em;
}
#text-5 > * {
  flex-basis: 40%;
}
.form {
  display: flex;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  #text-5 {
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="text-5">
  <img 
    src="https://shop.balancecoffee.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/ezgif.com-gif-maker-1.gif" 
    alt="Join Balance" 
  />
  <p>Join Balance and get 20% off your first order</p>
  <form class="form">
    <input type="text" value="Enter first name" />
    <input type="email" value="Enter email" />
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
  </form>
</div>
```